# Commons Math: Multiple Samples support for DescriptiveStatistics instances

Tags: java, statistics, apache-commons, apache-commons-math

I'm using the Apache Commons Math library to do some statistical analysis and it is working great so far. According to the [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html), I can accumulate the statistics produced by multiple `SummaryStatistics` instances using the convenient `AggregateSummaryStatistics` type.

However, the statistic I'm interested on is the Median, which I'm currently computing through the `getPercentile()` method of the `DescriptiveStatistics` type.

Do you know if there's an equivalent of the `AggregateSummaryStatistics` for `DescriptiveStatistics` instances? So far I had no luck browsing the library's Javadoc, and the alternative of having a separate `DescriptiveStatistics` instance for accumulation doesn't seem elegant.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 3.5 of Commons Math, there is no way to do this.  Watch https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MATH-1298 for updates.